# Show confirmation box then edit textbox field based on answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've got an asp.net webforms page which has a drop down filled with Categories.  If the user selects the Category "ER" or "DR", a Description textbox will be populated based on which one is chosen.  However, I need to inform the user that their text in the Description field will be lost if they switch categories.

**submit_ticket.aspx**

```
function ShowConfirmation(ddlCategory) {
    //Not sure what goes here.
}

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategory" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownList" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

**Submit_ticket.aspx.cs**

```
protected void ddlCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if ((ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text == "DR") || ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text == "ER")
            ddlCategory.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return ShowConfirmation(this);");

        if (ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text == "DR")
            txtDescription.Text = "DR Template";
        else if (ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text == "ER")
            txtDescription.Text = "ER Template";
    }
}
```

There are 7 Categories in total but I only need this functionality on the two listed above.  The "template" used for those Categories is long and it can't be an option to populate the Description textbox with Javascript.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the AutoPostBack from the dropdown and add your own js function to the onchange event.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="func();">
    <asp:ListItem Text="01"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="02"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="03"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In your js function get a response from the user. If 'yes', force a postback using the __doPostBack function built-in to asp.net. Include the name of the control and 'true' as parameters.

```
function func() {
    if (confirm("change?")) {
        // parameters are: '__EVENTTARGET' and '__EVENTARGUMENT'.
        __doPostBack("DropDownList1", "true");  
    }      
}
```

Check the __EVENTARGUMENT when the page loads.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT") == "true")
    {
        // call a method.
        TextChanger();
    }
}

protected void TextChanger()
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "02")
    {
        Label2.Text = "changed text";
    }
}
```